# Need help on Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The actually URL which my app uses is:

`http://site.com/gallery?id=23`
but I would like it to be possible to achieve the same with

`http://site.com/topic/place/new-delhi/gallery/23`
I have no experience of rewrite rules, how can I set this up?

where 'place' and 'new-delhi' are two dynamic values.
Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean saying *'place' and 'new-delhi' are two dynamic values*

The rule is :

```
RewriteRule /topic/([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/gallery/([0-9]*) /gallery?id=$3 [R=301]
```

With this rule, place is stored in $1 and new-delhi is stored in $2

You can get them like this

```
RewriteRule /topic/([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/gallery/([0-9]*) /gallery?var1=$1&city=$2&id=$3 [R=301]
```

If you go to `http://site.com/topic/place/new-delhi/gallery/23` you'll be redirected to `http://site.com/gallery?var1=place&city=new-delhi&id=23`

Comment: It cannot work since RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^topic/[^/]+/[^/]+/gallery/([^/]+)/?$ gallery?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```